# Javascript file CROSS DOMAIN true absolute path

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am developing a bookmarklet, that uses a JavaScript file, on **cross-domain**, and i need to catch the full absolute path of the JavaScript file;

Example, i store my JavaScript file on domain.com and i am accesing my script from *domain.org*

My JavaScript file is not on domain.org, i want to get this result: *domain.com*

Comment: So, whats the problem? You know the full absolute path where you store your JavaScript file.

Comment: yes, i know it, but i need a variable, something like $_SERVER from php; i don't want to setup the application each time i update the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the path in the js file it self:

```
var find_file_path = function (name) {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

    for (var i = scripts.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        var src = scripts[i].src;
        if (src.indexOf(name) > -1) {
            return src;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

var file_path = find_file_path(THE_NAME_OF_JS_FILE);
```

now file_path is the url of the file itself

Comment: whats with var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'); ? ... the idea is that you activate the bookmarklet, and you never know the structure of the website that you are on; i dont understand your code

Comment: how do you include this js file in your bookmarketlet? do you do it this way?
javascript:(function(){
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.src = JS_FILE_PATH;
    document.body.appendChild(newScript);
})();

Comment: not working;`var find_file_path = function (name) {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

    for (var i = scripts.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        var src = scripts[i].src;
        if (src.indexOf(name) > -1) {
            return src;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

var file_path = find_file_path('input.js');

    var projectURL = file_path;

console.log(project_url);` i get the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: project_url is not defined

Comment: yes, because you defined projectURL instead of project_url.. try correct it?

Comment: btw, my new link is like http://www.cnn.com/home/cnn/Discovery/bookmarklet/input.js?x=0.23214325453, can i get only the http://www.cnn.com/home/cnn/Discovery/bookmarklet/ ?

Comment: sure, do it this way: var s = "cnn.com/home/cnn/Discovery/bookmarklet/input.js?x=0.23214325453";
var result = s.split('input.js')[0];

Comment: but ofcourse, the split and the explode ... thx for reminding me